# How to make a recognition mural with separated parts?

Tags: image

Hopefully the title of this question wasn't so badly worded that it won't elicit answers but basically I am trying to achieve this sort of effect with extruded rectangles and squares:

[image]

The issue I am having is how to add photos onto a plane and have them all fit properly to the scale that they came in.  In other words, I have been opening images as planes and trying to get the poster to match them but as you can see in the screenshot below, it isn't practical to do it this way:[image]

Hopefully there is a solution to this kind of project.

Thanks

Comment: Create the pieces first and texture later. You can adjust the placement and scale by manipulating texture coordinates

Comment: Yep that worked!  Thanks

Comment: can you please write an answer to your own question. It might help other users with a similar project.